# Validation on listview Row that can disable a button outside of the listview

Tags: wpf

I have a listview that contains textboxes.  When a user enters data into the text box, I want to validate that data and then enable and disable a button that is not in the listview.
My code works if the textbox is not in a listview but once I add the textbox in the listview it no longer works. 
My question is how can I validate inside a listviewrow and use those results to disable a button?

```
<Button Height="35" Width="100" Content="Button">
        <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=text1, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>

                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>

 <ListView x:Name="AnimalView" ItemsSource="{Binding Animals, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="200" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox x:Name="text1"
                                 Style="{StaticResource TextErrorStyle}" >
                            <TextBox.Text>
                                <Binding Path="Name" 

                                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
                                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                        <val:ValidationName></val:ValidationName>
                                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                </Binding>
                            </TextBox.Text>
                        </TextBox>
                        <TextBox  Height="25" Width="100">
               <TextBox.Text>
                                <Binding Path="Name"  Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                              <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                        <val:ValidationName>
                                            </val:ValidationName>
                                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                </Binding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                   </TextBox>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

     public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<Animal> _animals;

    public List<Animal> Animals
    {
        get { return _animals; }
        set
        {
            _animals = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Animals);
        }
    }

    private String _name;

    public String Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Name);
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        List<AnimalType> AnimalTypes = new List<AnimalType>();
        AnimalTypes.Add( new AnimalType { Id = 1, Type = "Dog" });
        AnimalTypes.Add(new AnimalType { Id = 2, Type = "Cat" });

        Animals = new List<Animal>();
        Animals.Add(new Animal{Name="Poodle", AnimalType = new AnimalType { Id = 1, Type = "Dog" }, AnimalTypes=AnimalTypes});
        Animals.Add(new Animal { Name = "Siamese", AnimalType = new AnimalType { Id = 2, Type = "Cat" }, AnimalTypes = AnimalTypes } );
    }


}

public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AnimalType AnimalType { get; set; }
    public List<AnimalType> AnimalTypes { get; set; }
}

public class AnimalType
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the code for Animal class?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with following code:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=text1, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

If you look correctly, you are checking for validation errors in control with name text1, which WPF will find if it is outside somewhere in your view but not when it is inside `DataTemplate` as it is in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I realize that the problem is because it is in the dataTemplate but how do you fix it?

Comment: I guess I should ask is this even possible?

Comment: @winniemonster Nothing is impossible in codeland, it's just making it work will break good practice/patterns. You could use some kind of event mechanism to enable/disable button. Though, validator can invoke Error event in case of any validation errors, it will not invoke any events in case of successful validation.

Comment: What is the best practice for handling this then?

Comment: @winniemonster Why can't you add button in the template itself?

Comment: Because the button invokes an action on the whole grid not just on the row level.